# How does CLR match C++ file access constants with C# enums?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I would like to know how does CLR match `GENERIC_READ` with `FileAccess.Read`, for instance. I had marshalled this parameter as UnmanagedType.U4

`#define GENERIC_READ (0x80000000L)`

but

`FileAccess.Read = 1`

How does marshaler know what is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreateFile's dwDesiredAccessMode argument is too out of whack to cleanly map to an enum.  So FileAccess is mapped in code to an int. From the [Reference Source's](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) FileStream.cs source code file, FileStream.Init() method:

```
    int fAccess;
    ...
    fAccess = access == FileAccess.Read? GENERIC_READ:
    access == FileAccess.Write? GENERIC_WRITE:
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE;
    ...
    _handle = Win32Native.SafeCreateFile(tempPath, fAccess, ...etc)
```

Original indenting reproduced, odd as it looks.

Answer (score 0):

[Marshalling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66245/Marshaling-with-C-Chapter-1-Introducing-Marshaling)  is a conversion between types, not values. So in other words, I don't think the CLR will do anything to help you with your case.

If you have an unmanaged function accepting an integer (`GENERIC_READ`), and call it from .NET, you need to pass the value 0x80000000 and not 1. The CLR can't know that you want `FileAccess.Read` to be 0x80000000.

Comment: I just replaced all DWORDs in unmanaged CreateFile() with FileAccess, FileShare, FileMode and FileAttributes enumerations. And it works great.

Comment: That should match the FILE_READ_DATA = 1 constant then. I'm not very familiar with the CreateFile() API function, but I assume passing just FILE_READ_DATA is enough for successfully reading the file.